# Make outlook email tale text align vertically

Tags: html, html-email

I am having an issue where the first and last column look different to my middle columns in outlook HTML. If I open it on the web it is fine. It's just outlook on Windows that has this problem.

[image]

As you can see from the above picture

Here is my code. I am appending an HTML row to a template table as the data is dynamic

```
<table style="width:100%; border-spacing: 0px 5px; border-collapse:collapse;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    body += "<tr style=\"height: 50px;\">";
    body += "<td nowrap style=\"border: #e8d5d5 3px solid; border-right: none; font-size: 0.7em; width: 20%; vertical-align: middle\">"
        + HRTableModel.Fullname + "</td> <br/>";
    body += "<td nowrap style=\"border: #e8d5d5 3px solid; border-right: none; font-size: 0.7em; width: 20%; vertical-align: middle\">"
        + HRTableModel.KickoffDate.ToShortDateString() + "</td> <br/>";
    body += "<td nowrap style=\"border: #e8d5d5 3px solid; border-right: none; font-size: 0.7em; width: 20%; vertical-align: middle\">"
        + HRTableModel.ExitAction + "</td> <br/>";
    body += "<td nowrap style=\"border: #e8d5d5 3px solid; border-right: none; font-size: 0.7em; width: 20%; vertical-align: middle\">"
        + HRTableModel.ExitStatus + "</td> <br/>";
    body += "<td nowrap style=\"border: #e8d5d5 3px solid; font-size: 0.7em; width: 20%; vertical-align: middle\">"
        + HRTableModel.EmailStatus + "</td> <br/>";
    body += "</tr>";
</table>
```

Comment: Can you add the final (live) content? You may have extra data being unintentionally added

Answer (score 0):

Try to make an email status shorter.

"Email was sent successful" --> "Email's sent"

I suppose, Outlook sees >3 words and prepares a free space for line breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all "vertical-align: middle" and instead increasing the cellpadding. This should auto adjust your table data and fix the formatting issues, allowing the client to readjust as necessary.. just tested on outlook and it works, you can also use something like stripo to see how your email will look across all instances of outlook before sending.

```
<table style="border: solid 1px #e8d5d5; font-size: 1.3em" cellpadding="20" rules="all">
 <tr style="height: 50px;">
    <td>john doe</td>
    <td>6/9/>20</td>
    <td>resignation</td>
    <td>claim commenced</td>
    <td>email was sent successfully</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 50px;">
    <td>jane doe</td>
    <td>6/9/>20</td>
    <td>resignation</td>
    <td>claim commenced</td>
    <td>email was sent successfully</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```